# How to sort a subset according to some ordered superset?

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

Suppose I have an unsorted array of strings; let's call this set A. Each string in this array also exists in a larger array of strings, set B, where the larger array is sorted in some arbitrary way.

I want to sort A such that:

For each element E in A,

- All other elements of A which appear before E in B also appear before E in A
- All other elements of A which appear after E in B also appear before E in B

For example, assume set B to be: [Cow, Horse, Pig, Chicken, Goat, Dog]
Assume unsorted set A to be: [Horse, Dog, Pig, Cow]

After sorting, set A should look like: [Cow, Horse, Pig, Dog]

My initial thought on how to tackle this is to build a new set, or in VBA, an array of strings:

- Declare new array C
- Iterate through elements of B

  - If element of B exists in A, append element to C

Array C now comprises of all elements in A, in the order that they appear in B

While I am fairly confident that this approach works (albeit not very efficiently if B is far larger than A), I would like to know if anyone has some advice on how to do this more efficiently, taking into consideration best practices, modularity/flexibility, etc. I am looking to implement this in VBA, but pseudocode should suffice. Thanks! (Sorry for the sloppy formatting; first time posting here!)

Comment: Yes. That will work. Efficiency, best practices, modularity/flexibility, etc, all depend on the actual *implementation*. It's hard to review code that hasn't been written yet.

Comment: @Comintern , Thanks for the input. I will update the post once I have implemented a function to do what I have described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've been looking at recordsets rather a lot [this month on my blog](https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/10/) and so I can tell you that your use case is suited to using an ADO recordset.

In the code below you can see that we have a master set and then we can filter to a subset.  Also in the code we take a take snapshot to a variant array showing the sort order.  Then we sort the master set on another field which changes the sorting of the subset as well as can be seen in the second snapshot.

```
Option Explicit

'* Tools->References
'ADODB      Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll

Sub Test()

    Dim rstADO As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim fld As ADODB.Field

    Set rstADO = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rstADO
        .Fields.Append "Animal", adVarChar, 20
        .Fields.Append "BirthDay", adDate, FieldAttributeEnum.adFldKeyColumn
        .Fields.Append "ArrivalSequence", adInteger

        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockPessimistic
        .Open

        .AddNew Array("Animal", "BirthDay", "ArrivalSequence"), Array("Cow", Now() - 200, 1)
        .AddNew Array("Animal", "BirthDay", "ArrivalSequence"), Array("Horse", Now() - 100, 2)
        .AddNew Array("Animal", "BirthDay", "ArrivalSequence"), Array("Pig", Now() - 150, 3)
        .AddNew Array("Animal", "BirthDay", "ArrivalSequence"), Array("Chicken", Now() - 120, 4)
        .AddNew Array("Animal", "BirthDay", "ArrivalSequence"), Array("Goat", Now() - 180, 5)
        .AddNew Array("Animal", "BirthDay", "ArrivalSequence"), Array("Dog", Now() - 140, 5)


        .Filter = "Animal='Cow' or Animal='Dog' or Animal='Pig'  or Animal='Horse'"

        Dim vSnap As Variant
        .MoveFirst
        vSnap = .GetRows

        Debug.Assert vSnap(0, 0) = "Cow"
        Debug.Assert vSnap(0, 1) = "Horse"
        Debug.Assert vSnap(0, 2) = "Pig"
        Debug.Assert vSnap(0, 3) = "Dog"


        '*
        '* Now sort according to birthday
        '*
        .Sort = "BirthDay"


        Dim vSnap2 As Variant
        .MoveFirst
        vSnap2 = .GetRows

        Debug.Assert vSnap2(0, 0) = "Cow"
        Debug.Assert vSnap2(0, 1) = "Pig"
        Debug.Assert vSnap2(0, 2) = "Dog"
        Debug.Assert vSnap2(0, 3) = "Horse"


    End With

End Sub
```

[Excel Development Platform: VBA - Fabricate an ADO Recordset for Sorting and Filtering](https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/10/vba-fabricate-ado-recordset-for-sorting.html)

Comment: Thanks so much! I have virtually no knowledge of or experience with SQL, ActiveX, or any related technologies, but I think now I have a place to start, given that it seems to be directly tied to what it is I'm trying to achieve.Perhaps this isn't the best time & place to ask, but is there anything in particular that you suggest I read up on, so that I can get to a point where I can intuitively digest and fully understand everything in the code you've provided?

Comment: Well, if you are a noobie with a voracious appetite to read I'd suggest you learn C# instead.  C# is more modern and has some great list and collection classes.